# OpenCV merge failing to merge image channel

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I'm attempting to add Gaussian noise to a single channel of an image.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img1 = cv.imread('input/foo.png')
img1_blue, img1_green, img1_red = cv.split(img1)
img1_h, img1_w, _ = img1.shape

s = 5
noise = np.random.normal(0, s, (img1_h, img1_w))
img1_gn = img1_green + noise

print(img1_green.shape) # (512, 384)
print(img1_gn.shape)    # (512, 384)
print(img1_blue.shape)  # (512, 384)

img1_g_noise = cv.merge((img1_blue, img1_gn, img1_red))
```

This results in the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-049cf9e65133> in <module>
     13 
---> 14 img1_g_noise = cv.merge((img1_blue, img1_gn, img1_red))
     15 

error: OpenCV(3.4.5) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/merge.cpp:293: error: (-215:Assertion failed) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function 'merge'
```

I'm not sure how or why this is happening. The resulting noisy green channel has the same dimensions and type as the other two channels. Recombining the original green channel works just fine. Any steering direction is appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because noise and channel datatype mismatch. numpy matrix has default datatype of numpy.float64. and you have to define noise in type of rach channel by adding `.astype(img1_blue.dtype)` to noise defenition.

edited code :

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img1 = cv.imread('list.JPG')
img1_blue, img1_green, img1_red = cv.split(img1)
img1_h, img1_w, _ = img1.shape

s = 5
noise = np.random.normal(0, s, (img1_h, img1_w)).astype(img1_blue.dtype)
img1_gn = img1_green + noise

print(img1_green.shape) # (512, 384)
print(img1_gn.shape)    # (512, 384)
print(img1_blue.shape)  # (512, 384)

img1_g_noise = cv.merge((img1_blue, img1_gn, img1_red))
cv.imshow("img1_g_noise",img1_g_noise)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the `dtype` problem.

by default, the `image_blue` and `image_red` are `uint8` type; 
but the `noise` is `float16` type.

---

**Solution1**

you can change the `noise` to 'unint8` type by：

```
noise = noise.astype('image_red.type')
```

but this will let the noise loss much information.

---

**Solution2**

you can also change the all of the rgb channel to `float16` dtype, by  adding this two line:

```
img1_blue = img1_blue.astype(img1_gn.dtype)
img1_red = img1_red.astype(img1_gn.dtype)
```